# Redo all the migrations on symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

After I had a bug in php my admin I deleted all the tables from it to solve it.

Now I want to rebuild my database using doctrine migrations (but not the very last migration as it is the one which caused the bug).

How can I make a migration at an previous state?

Edit : by doing the migrate command it recreates my table however everytime I try a new

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

I get the following error messages :

> [notice] Migrating up to DoctrineMigrations\Version20201124181841
> [error] Migration DoctrineMigrations\Version20201124174448 failed
> during Execution. Error: "An exception occurred while executing
> 'CREATE TABLE publishers (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name
> VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, contact_firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
> contact_lastname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, contact_email VARCHAR(255) NOT
> NULL, contact_phonecode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, contact_phone
> VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, public_phonecode VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
> public_phone VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, public_email VARCHAR(255)
> DEFAULT NULL, website VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, logo VARCHAR(255)
> DEFAULT NULL, facebook VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, twitter VARCHAR(255)
> DEFAULT NULL, instagram VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, address
> VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, city VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, zip
> VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
> company_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, registration_date DATETIME NOT
> NULL, modification_date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, description LONGTEXT
> DEFAULT NULL, tagline VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, slug VARCHAR(255) NOT
> NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE
> `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB':
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
> 'publishers' already exists"
>
> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 57:
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE publishers (id
> INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) N   OT NULL,
> contact_firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, contact_lastname VARCHAR(255)
> NOT NULL, contact_email VARCHAR(255   ) NOT NULL, contact_phonecode
> VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, contact_phone VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
> public_phonecode VARCHAR(   255) DEFAULT NULL, public_phone
> VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, public_email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
> website VARCHAR(   255) DEFAULT NULL, logo VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
> facebook VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, twitter VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT
> NULL, instagram VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, address VARCHAR(255)
> DEFAULT NULL, city VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, zip   VARCHAR(255)
> DEFAULT NULL, country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, company_number
> VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, registration_date D   ATETIME NOT NULL,
> modification_date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, description LONGTEXT DEFAULT
> NULL, tagline VARCHAR(255)   DEFAULT NULL, slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE
> `utf8mb4_unicode_c   i` ENGINE = InnoDB':
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
> 'publishers' already exists
>
> In Exception.php line 18:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
> 'publishers' already exists
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 52:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
> 'publishers' already exists
>
> doctrine:migrations:migrate [--write-sql [WRITE-SQL]] [--dry-run]
> [--query-time] [--allow-no-migration] [--all-or-nothing
> [ALL-OR-NOTHING]] [--configuration CONFIGURATION] [--db-configuration
> DB-CONFIGURATION] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
> [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env
> ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  []

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can migrate to a chosen migration number, say there are 10 migrations and you want to migrate all except 10

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate 9
```

where 9 should be replaced with migration timestamp, for instance 20201124100000

Or, you could backup last migration in case you need it, delete the original so there's only 9 left in the folder and run

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Or, you can execute them one by one, just keep count not to execute the last one

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate first-migration-timestamp
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate next
```